# AngularJS: how should I set the params for $http dynamically?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am very new with AngularJS. Thank you for answer. My code is as follow:

```
mainModule.controller('MainController', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('http://localhost/backend/WebService.php', {params: {entity: 'IndexPageEntity'}}).
    success(function(data) {
        $scope.intro = data[0].IndexPageContent;
});
$http.get('http://localhost/backend/WebService.php', {params: {entity: 'ExhibitionServiceEntity'}}).
    success(function(data) {
        $scope.exhibit = data[0].ExhibitionServiceContent;
});
$http.get('http://localhost/backend/WebService.php', {params: {entity: 'ShootingServiceEntity'}}).
    success(function(data) {
        $scope.shooting = data[0].ShootingServiceContent;
});
});
```

My html file would be:

```
<div ng-controller="MainController">
<div>{{intro}}</div>
<div>{{exhibit}}</div>
<div>{{shooting}}</div>
</div>
```

I believe there must be some ways to improve the above code in order to reduce repetition. What I want is to pass entity parameter to the controller on creation.

Using ng-init to pass parameter is discouraged, according to the documentation. Writing custom directive to pass argument to scope does not work since parameters would be overwrittern.

What is the best practice to set params dynamically for use in $http? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move all the logic to a service and use a directive. I would suggest you to modify your backend to return the same structured data, instead of IndexPageContent, ExhibitionServiceContent, etc. it should be Content or whatever name you want to use. But for now I've added a replace function to get the name of the content from the name of the entity.

```
mainModule.factory('webService', function($http) {
    var apiUrl = 'http://localhost/backend/WebService.php';

    function getContent(params) {
        var config = {
            'params': params
        };
        return $http.get(apiUrl, config);
    };

    return {
        getContent: function(params) {
            return getContent(params)
        }
     };
});

mainModule.controller('MainController', function($scope, webService) {
    var params = {
        'entity': $scope.entity
    };

    var contentName = $scope.entity.replace('Entity', 'Content');

    webService.getContent(params).then(function (data) {
       $scope.content = data[0][contentName];
    }); 

});

mainModule.directive('EntityContent', function() {
    return {
        controller: 'MainController',
        replace: true,
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
          entity: '@entity'
        },
        template: '<div>{{ content }}</div>'          
     };
});

<div>
  <entity-content entity="IndexPageEntity">
  <entity-content entity="ExhibitionServiceEntity">
  <entity-content entity="ShootingServiceEntity">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. Then how should i set the param in html side?

Comment: I see, then what you probably want to use it's a directive. Let me update the answer.

Comment: Thanks for answer. In fact my backend yields json like [{IndexPage_id: "1", IndexPageContent: "Something"}]

Comment: Was it helpful? Did you solve it? Then please accept it!

Comment: Yes, I have figured it out finally. When you understand how to employ directive, then everything is easy. Thank you.

Comment: Why is there no more direct way to pass parameters to controller?

Comment: It's part of the separation of concerns, controllers are the glue among your services and views. I agree though in that once you understand directives everything it's easier. But I don't know what you mean with a more direct way.

Comment: For instance, use ng-init to pass data to controller. But that is discouraged in the documentation

Answer (score 0):

Create an object data and send the value for the key inside the object at every call.. Also pass the value for key to be set inside the scope..

E.g.

```
   $scope.makeHttpCall = function(data) {
       $http.get('http://localhost/backend/WebService.php', {params: data}).
        success(function(data) {
            $scope[$scope.key] = data[0][$scope.key];
       });
};
```

you can then call this function as

```
$scope.key = 'IndexPageContent';

 data = {
        entity : 'yourValueHere'
    };

$scope.makeHttpCall(data);
```

You can set other values as well inside the scope that are dynamic for each request..

I hope this makes sense to you...

Comment: Thank for answer. But how should I set $scope.key in html? I am not using ng-model since I am not using input. Thanks.......

Comment: Not an appropriate approach, but you can do something like this.. you can write like this...   <div class=""{{methodToSetTheParameter()}}">

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you want to set the class value and then let the controller retrieves the value and then use it to set the param. Am I correct?

Comment: Nope.. You instead just make a call to the function, which will set the $scope.key value.. I told you that it is not the best way, but you indirectly set the $scope.key value from HTML..